# How the salesforce database is safe

Tags: force.com

Most of the time I use to here this question that how can you say that salesforce database is safe as it is shared with different peoples at a time? How can you prove it that my date is safe and it is secure? How can i mentain my salesforce database? Can anyone provide me some useful material and demo over this issue.

Comment: I think this too broad and opinion base.

Comment: Can you edit the question and clarify what you're worried about more specifically? How data is protected from being accessed in other organizations besides yours?

Answer (score 1):

This question is far too broad for our community to answer effectively.

Take a look at Salesforce.com's whitepapers on security and the design of the platform and its multi-tenant architecture.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Private_Trustworthy_Force.com_Whitepaper

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture